# Ranking performance measure

Tags: ranking, model-evaluation

I have a system able to produce a ranking of some operations according to their  anomalous score. I have N anomalous operations inside the dataset, which I expect to be in the first N positions (best case). 
This score is computed by a formula which has some parameters. According to the parameters configurations obviously the ranking changes.
How can I measure the performance quality of the system? Currently, I am measuring the true positive rate, but I would prefer some measure that shows how much the anomalous operations are concentrated in the first positions. What I mean is that I can have the same TPR but in one case the FNs can be in N+1, ..., N+10 position, right after the Nth position, and another case where the FNs are at the end of the ranking. I definitely prefer the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [average precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Average_precision), that you will compute on each element in the dataset, and then you will obtain [mean average precision (MAP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Mean_average_precision)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use it. It seems to be exactly I was looking for! 
Instead, what do you think about [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Discounted_cumulative_gain)? Can it be also a good measure if I found a way to define the "relevance" variable?

Comment: Well, it could be, but really for your problem, the standard is MAP.